# Android Studio manage default imports

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an app with help of `RxJava` and I am annoyed with Android Studio auto-importing `java.util.Observable` every time I write `Observable` but I want to use `rx.Observable` import and not `java.util.Observable`. I don't want to disable `auto-import`, but maybe there is a way to manually set default import?

Comment: Which `Observable` class are you using?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice edited my question

Answer (score 2):

For Windows/Linux, you can go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import

Answer (score 1):

When you open File->Settings, there is a search box at the top left corner of the Settings dialog. Type "Auto Import" there to find all the options related to this feature. Alternatively, you can push Ctrl-Shift-A (Cmd-Shift-A on Mac) and type "Auto Import". This will search all menu commands and settings for the words you type. Both of these methods will lead you to Editor->General->Auto Import in Settings.

Another great feature is Quick Fixes which you activate by pressing Alt-Enter in the Code Editor. When the insertion point is on an unresolved name, the Quick Fixes menu includes "Import class". When there are multiple classes with the same name, it gives you a list of all the choices and you can select the one you want.